# LinearLayout leaving out too much white space. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I am writing an Android app that helps little kids learn maths. It gives the user some questions and the user would answer them. If he/she answers all of them correctly, a prize would be given. Now I need to tell the user about this in the `ResultsActivity`. Here is how it looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:context="com.smartkidslovemaths.ResultsActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/left_side"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/score_label"
            android:textSize="@dimen/score_label_size"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="100"
            android:id="@+id/score_value"
            android:textSize="@dimen/score_size"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_side"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/question_display_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the left side of the screen is used to display the score. The right side (The `LinearLayout` with the id `right_side`) is empty because it would have different things in it depending on whether the user answers all the questions correctly. If he/she doesn't, it would display which question(s) did he/she did wrongly. That means I need to add views dynamically to the `LinearLayout`. After a few tries, I am able to display the prize that the user gets and some text telling him/her. However, there are lots of empty between the text and the `ImageView`! Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Hope you don't mind that this is Chinese. As you can see, there are lots of space between the tip of the star and the text. (I even need to scroll down a little to see the star!) Now here is my code to add the views:

```
private void displayPrize () { //This is called in the onCreate() method
    Resources res = getResources ();
    int marginAll = (int)res.getDimension (R.dimen.prize_display_margin);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams (FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parentParams.setMargins (marginAll, marginAll, marginAll, marginAll);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.right_side)).setLayoutParams (parentParams);

    TextView text = new TextView (this);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
    text.setLayoutParams (textParams);
    QuestionOptions options = QuestionsActivity.Options.getOptions ();

    switch (options.getDigitCount ()) {
        case 1:
        default:
            text.setText (res.getText (R.string.earn_star_text));
            break;
        case 2:
            text.setText (res.getText (R.string.earn_badge_text));
            break;
        case 3:
            text.setText (res.getText (R.string.earn_trophy_text));
            break;
    }

    text.setTextSize (res.getDimension (R.dimen.answer_text_size) / 1.5F);

    ((LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.right_side)).addView (text);

    ImageView image = new ImageView (this);
    image.setLayoutParams (imageParams);
    int resID = QuestionOptionMaps.getOptionsDrawableMap ().get (options);
    image.setImageResource (resID);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById (R.id.right_side)).addView (image);
}
```

I tired a lot of times by changing those `wrap_content` and `match_parent` stuff. And every time it didn't work. I even tried to add weights to the views! And I'm sure that the image is a perfect square so the white space isn't caused by the image.

Just for clarity, here is the dimens.xml and strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_margin">25dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="customize_menu_title">15pt</dimen>
    <dimen name="customize_menu_radio">13pt</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_text_size">20pt</dimen>
    <dimen name="answer_text_size">12pt</dimen>

    <dimen name="radio_button_spacing">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="item_spacing">20dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="score_label_size">20pt</dimen>
    <dimen name="score_size">40pt</dimen>
    <dimen name="question_display_margin">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="prize_display_margin">32dp</dimen>
</resources>

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Smart Kids Love Maths</string>

    <string name="button_trophies">My Prizes</string>
    <string name="button_start">Start!</string>

    <string name="digit_text">Number of digits</string>
    <string name="operator_text">Operation</string>
    <string name="timer_enabled_text">Timer Enabled</string>
    <string name="title_activity_questions">Smart Kids Love Maths</string>

    <string name="title_activity_results">Results</string>
    <string name="score_label">Your Score:</string>

    <string name="correct_text">Correct!</string>
    <string name="wrong_text">Wrong!</string>
    <string name="correct_answer_text">Correct Answer: </string>
    <string name="earn_trophy_text">You earned a new trophy!</string>
    <string name="earn_badge_text">You earned a new badge!</string>
    <string name="earn_star_text">You earned a new star!</string>
</resources>
```

Can you tell me why this is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing your `imageParams` to `WRAP_CONTENT` in both dimensions as well?

Comment: @PauloAvelar Because the image is kind of big, I think that would enlarge it to its actual size, right?

Comment: @PauloAvelar Now I tried it, still white space

Comment: Yes, it would. I recommend you resize it later in your project. Is there any reason why you can't add it to your XML layout as `invisible` and then set the text and image source before displaying it? This would help you design and preview the final layout.

Comment: It's not LinearLayout's problem. You need to call "setAdjustViewBounds(true)" for the large ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the imageView is larger than its parent, use imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true) to keep its size ratio.

You can see the differences between the attached images.

```
    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Test Right 1");
    textView.setTextSize(32);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linear.addView(textView, tParams);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.img);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // This is the trick
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams iParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linear.addView(imageView, iParams);
```

[image: before set]

[image: after]