# Why my TextView under an ImageView is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-xml

I am writing an Android game. In the level selection activity's layout file, I want to layout the levels' buttons (They are actually `ImageView`s) like this:

```
x x x
x x x
```

And each level button has a `TextView`, with that level's name as the text, below it (Let's call these two views together as a "level choice"). I used a lot of `LinearLayout`s to do this. Here is the code for a level choice:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/angles"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/angles_level"
        android:textSize="@dimen/level_text_size"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the two views' height and width are all `wrap_content`. But when I look at the designer, the text view doesn't show up.When I select the text view in the component tree, it shows where the text view is:

[image]

P.S. The picture isn't showing all six levels because I haven't made them yet.

As you can see, the text view is right at the bottom! When I select the `ImageView`, it shows that it is occupying all the space of its parent!

[image]

I don't know why this is happening, my image is certainly a square! Can you explain why this is happening and how do I fix it?

If you need my whole layout code, feel free to tell me in the comments.

Comment: You need to use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. LinearLayout does not allow 2 or more objects to occupy the same space. If you want that to happen, you need to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: LInearLayout ? why not relative layout it give you more flexible options

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout, and align the top of the ImageView to the top of the TextView, you'll see that both views take up the same space then.

Comment: You can do one thing to check weather your text area present in the view or not, just add background color in the text view and check visible or not ?

Comment: use a table layout with rows and coloms

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe your textview color default is white

Comment: I don't want to use a `RelativeLayout` because I find it difficult to remember what attributes to set, Linear layouts are more straightforward (for me at least) @SyedNazarMuhammad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the best solution is to position and size it properly by code (where you have total control) instead of xml.

Anyway, i think your problem can be solved by setting ImageViews ScaleType

```
imageView1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_START);
```

By XML:

```
  android:scaleType="fit_start"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use background color for textview when I'm studying the layout.

If you use wrap content in both dimension for TextView, that is invisible since you did not write any text inside it. wrap content means that the view take the minimum space. And no text means 0px; try to set ImageView and TextView with layout_weight 1 and layout_height 0dp. In this way both view take half of space of parent layout

Answer (score 0):

Because right now, your LinearLayout doesn't know how to distribute the ratio of its children. And in fact, your imageview's wrap content already 
consumes the whole space.

So, LinearLayout says "Sorry TextView, you have no space left".

Use `layout_weight` to both of the children.
I guess you want to have your picture twice the size of your text. 
2:1

That is,

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight=2
      android:src="@drawable/angles"/>
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight=1
      android:text="@string/angles_level"
      android:textSize="@dimen/level_text_size"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I posted a question about `ImageView`s leaving out too much whitespace:

[LinearLayout leaving out too much white space. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261563/linearlayout-leaving-out-too-much-white-space-why)

I think this is the same as that problem. So I tried setting `adjustViewBounds` to true in the xml. And it works! Now the image view look like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/parallel_lines"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

       <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/angles"/>
       <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/angles_level"
          android:textSize="@dimen/level_text_size"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

or simple you can set background of textview to that image by putting this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/angles_level"
    android:background="@drawable/angles"
    android:textSize="@dimen/level_text_size"/>
```